# Is it possible to add a parent to json file?

Tags: python-3.x

This should be a very very simple to just add a parent to json file!!! But I can't find any code that works!
Here is the json file I have:

```
[
    { "id": "123", "name": "ABC" },
    { "id": "456", "name": "DEF" }
]
```

and here is what I need:

```
[
  { "id": "0", "name": "Managers", "children": [
    { "id": "123", "name": "ABC" },
    { "id": "456", "name": "DEF" }] 
  }
]
```

I have found the following code from other pages which **didn't work**:

```
with open ("myfile.json", 'r') as f:
    myjson = json.load(f)

myjson = {'Main Parent': myjson}
```

PLEASE HELP! It's been 8 hours I can't  find anything for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you want to hardcode it or what! But if you just want to do that then you can try this:

```
mylist=[
    { "id": "123", "name": "ABC" },
    { "id": "456", "name": "DEF" }
]

newlist=[{ "id": "0", "name": "Managers", "children": mylist}]

print(newlist)
"""
[{'id': '0',
  'name': 'Managers',
  'children': [{'id': '123',
                'name': 'ABC'}, 
               {'id': '456',
                'name': 'DEF'}
               ]
}]
"""
```

Comment: I tested it, it just added another object to the json file. like:
[
    {
        "id": "0",
        "name": "Managers",
        "children": []
    },

It's close! All I need is to move all objects into the children!

Comment: @user16514127 it is working perfectly fine if I import `myjson` from file as well

Comment: @user16514127 Your expected output is what I have printed there, right?

Comment: YOU WERE RIGHT! I just had the code in a wrong place! Thank you so much!!!